# Image orientation in a Camera2 preview

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I want to display the image from a camera in a `TextureView`. So far, the image is displayed but it's scale and orientation are incorrect.
For the scale, I use the following code to adjust the preview dimension to the image one's.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the displayed image has an incorrect ratio. The scale is greater on the horizontal axis compared to the vertical axis.

For the rotation, I compute the orientation using the formula given in [Camera Preview Android Dev](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/camera-preview). The result is then sent to the camera using `CaptureRequest.CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION` before a new `CaptureRequest` is created.

In portrait mode, everything is fine, but in landscape orientation, the image is rotated +/-90°. And in inverse portrait, it's flipped!

Does anyone know the origin of the problem and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the scaling issue, you could try setting the aspect ratio of the TextureView to match the aspect ratio of the camera preview size. You can do this by setting the width and height of the TextureView based on the aspect ratio of the camera preview size. You could do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (mPreviewSize != null) {
        int previewWidth = mPreviewSize.getWidth();
        int previewHeight = mPreviewSize.getHeight();

        if (width > height) {
            // Landscape
            int tmp = previewWidth;
            previewWidth = previewHeight;
            previewHeight = tmp;
        }

        if (height < previewHeight * width / previewWidth) {
            width = height * previewWidth / previewHeight;
        } else {
            height = width * previewHeight / previewWidth;
        }
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

As for the rotation issue, you could try rotating the TextureView instead of rotating the image. You could do this by setting the rotation of the TextureView based on the device orientation. Something like:

```
int displayRotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
int textureViewRotation = 0;

switch (displayRotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        textureViewRotation = 90;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        textureViewRotation = 0;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        textureViewRotation = 270;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        textureViewRotation = 180;
        break;
}

textureView.setRotation(textureViewRotation);
```

Make sure to apply these changes after the TextureView is attached to the camera preview session.